# my php code returns to many tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with 3 tables and 6 to 20 rows in each, but my PHP code creates 8 tables when there should be only 2 (2 post in the DB)

But why does it do that, I took the code from a different PHP page, where it works fine?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Brand check</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <br />
        <?php   
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM under_etage, sal_1, sal_2") or die(mysql_error());  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))  {
        ?>
        <table width="1100" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"lass="bold_font">
              <tr>
                  <td width="150" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;<?php echo $row["etDate"]; ?></td>
                  <td width="100" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Lys</td>
                  <td width="100" height="25" class="info">&nbsp;Skilt</td>
                  <td width="100" class="info" >&nbsp;Brandt&aelig;ppe</td>
                  <td width="100" class="info">&nbsp;Brand spr&oslash;jte</td>
                  <td width="500" class="info">&nbsp;D&oslash;re</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td height="20" class="split">Underetage</td>
                  <td width="50" class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td class="sort_bar">Opgang A</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info" ><?php echo $row["lys_u_a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_u_a"]; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td height="25" class="sort_bar">Studie/gang</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_u_s"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_s"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_u_s"]; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td height="25" class="sort_bar">Opgang B</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_u_b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_u_b"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td height="25" class="sort_bar">Bar - Festrum</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_u_bar"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_bar"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td height="25" class="sort_bar">Opgang C</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_u_c"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_c"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_u_c"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td height="25" class="sort_bar">Opgang D</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_u_d"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_u_d"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_u_d"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td height="20" class="split">Etager</td>
                  <td width="50" class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td class="grey_bar">1. Sal A</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_1a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_1a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_1a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_1a"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_1a"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td class="grey_bar">1. Sal B</td>
                  <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_1b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_1b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_1b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_1b"]; ?></td>
                  <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_1b"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">1. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_1c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_1c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_1c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_1c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_1c"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">1. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_1d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_1d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_1d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_1d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_1d"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">2. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_2a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_2a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_2a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_2a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_2a"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">2. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_2b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_2b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_2b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_2b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_2b"]; ?></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">2. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_2c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_2c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_2c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_2c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_2c"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">2. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_2d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_2d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_2d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_2d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_2d"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">3. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_3a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_3a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_3a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_3a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_3a"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">3. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_3b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_3b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_3b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_3b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_3b"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">3. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_3c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_3c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_3c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_3c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_3c"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">3. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_3d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_3d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_3d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_3d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_3d"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">4. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_4a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_4a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_4a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_4a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_4a"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">4. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_4b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_4b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_4b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_4b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_4b"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">4. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_4c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_4c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_4c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_4c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_4c"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">4. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_4d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_4d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_4d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_4d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_4d"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">5. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_5a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_5a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_5a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_5a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_5a"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">5. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_5b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_5b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_5b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_5b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_5b"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">5. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_5c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_5c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_5c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_5c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_5c"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="grey_bar">5. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar" ><?php echo $row["lys_5d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_5d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_5d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_5d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_5d"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">6. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_6a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_6a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_6a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_6a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_6a"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">6. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_6b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_6b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_6b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_6b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_6b"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">6. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_6c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_6c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_6c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_6c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_6c"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr >
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="sort_bar">6. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info"><?php echo $row["lys_6d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_6d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bt_6d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["bs_6d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["doors_6d"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="grey_bar">7. Sal A</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["lys_7a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_7a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_7a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_7a"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_7a"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="grey_bar">7. Sal B</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["lys_7b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_7b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_7b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_7b"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_7b"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="grey_bar">7. Sal C</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["lys_7c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_7c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_7c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_7c"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_7c"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="25" class="grey_bar">7. Sal D</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["lys_7d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["skilt_7d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bt_7d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["bs_7d"]; ?></td>
                <td class="grey_bar"><?php echo $row["doors_7d"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20" class="split">Taget</td>
                <td width="50"  class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="split">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="14" class="sort_bar">Taget</td>
                <td width="50" height="25" class="info" ><?php echo $row["lys_t"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["skilt_t"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["brand_s_t"]; ?></td>
                <td class="info"><?php echo $row["door_t"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to join properly. Show the table structure in the question along with the relations.

Comment: What is the meaning of `php code create 8 tables`? Did you create DB table using php?

Comment: @Ranjith The PHP code is creating `<table>`s.

Comment: ever heard about `for` cycle? [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: You code is creating one HTML table for every returned row. The number of rows you are returning is equal to the number of rows on table under_etage * the number of rows on table sal_1 * the number of rows on table sal_2 (if 20 rows on each table that is 8000 returned rows). You need to specify the conditions to join the tables on to avoid this

Comment: @Uriel_SVK isn't a `while` cycle the same here? What's the gain in using a `for`?

Comment: no the the code is creating 4 table (in html) for each post in my db.

Comment: http://overskov-hansen.dk/Brand.php

Comment: @DamienPirsy ment it for the "x. SAL y" rows.

Comment: Post the declares of the 3 tables and the data that is producing the extra output. Your joins have no conditions so will produce every possible combination of the rows on the 3 tables (hence if 20 rows on each, the number of output rows is 20 * 20 * 20 = 8000). Likely that you need to specify the columns that link the rows of the tables together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this example and use your data trust me it will work

```
// set up your query within a variable to make it easier to work with
$query = "SELECT * FROM people";

$result = mysql_query($query); //this will conect to the database and select the table to run the query on and return the values from that table.

// now we will set up a while loop to retrieve the information from the database table.
 while ($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h3>". $person['name'] ."</h3>"; // this line will fetch the query result that is stored in the $person variable and find the row ['name'] and display it on screen
    echo "<p>". $person['info'] ."</p>"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you broke the query into sections so the first query selected * from the one table and the next query selected data the other table then pass both variables thru the `mysql_fetch_array($query1, $query2)`

Comment: I got it down to 2 tabel in html/php, for each post in the db..

I am using where under_etage.etDate = sal_1.etDate

But I cant get it to work, if I want to compair in all 3 tabels.

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM under_etage, sal_1, sal_2 where under_etage.etDate = sal_1.etDate = sal_2.etDate ") or die(mysql_error());